# Flask: Difference between google cloud functions and google web deploy

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am a newbie who wants to deploy his flask app using google cloud functions. When I am searching it online, people are telling me to deploy it as a Flask app. I want to ask if there is any difference between those two. 
A cloud instance or deploying flask app on google cloud VS cloud serverless function

Answer (score 2):

As described by John and Kolban, Cloud Functions is a single purpose endpoint. You want to perform 1 thing, deploy 1 function.

However, if you want to have a many consistent things, like a microservice, you will have to deploy several endpoints that allow you to perform a CRUD on the same data object. You should prefer to deploy several endpoints (CRUD) and to have the capability to easily reuse class and object definitions and business logic. For this, a Flask webserver is that I recommend (and I prefer, I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-cloud-function-what-i-use-and-why-12bb5d3798e1)).

A packaging in Cloud Run is the best for having a serverless platform and pay-per-use pricing model (and automatic scaling and...).

There is an additional great thing: [Cloud Functions request object is based on Flask request object](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#stateless_functions). By the way, and it's that I also present in my article, it's easy to switch from one platform to another one. You only have to choose according with your requirements, your skills,... I also [wrote another article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-vs-cloud-functions-whats-the-lowest-cost-728d59345a2e)

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy your Flask app as an application in a Compute Engine VM instance, you are basically configuring a computer and application to run your code.  The notion of Cloud Functions relieves you from the chore and toil of having to create and manage the environment in which your program runs.  A marketing mantra is "You bring the code, we bring the environment".  When using Cloud Functions all you need do is code your application logic.  The maintenance of the server, scaling up as load increases, making sure the server is available and much more is taken care of for you.  When you run your code in your own VM instance, it is your responsibility to manage the whole environment.

References:

- [HTTP Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http)
- [Deploying a Python serverless function in minutes with GCP](https://medium.com/google-cloud/deploying-a-python-serverless-function-in-minutes-with-gcp-19dd07e19824)

Comment: If I want a little bit of User interface with functions, it is possible?

Comment: Google Cloud Functions is designed to provide you a Microservices environment.  Basically, it is designed to allow you to provide REST processing or event processing (Pub/Sub or GCS files).  Assuming by "User Interface" you mean returning HTML to a browser to allow the user to interact, that is usually best served by static HTML.  If that HTML needs dynamic data, it may make a REST call via Ajax and here is where a Cloud Function would come into play.  The Cloud Function could satisfy the REST service call made from the browser and return the dynamic data.

Comment: @AzamFarooqi - Cloud Functions is not designed to be a web server in the sense you are thinking about. Given that, you can provide a "user interface" to the user with the returned data. An example is formatting data retrieved by Cloud Functions into a table or list. That, however, is just basic HTML and is not directly related to Flask or Cloud Functions. You can even add CSS and Javascript to provide fancier displays. Remember that Cloud Functions is not a web server. Cloud Functions provides an HTTP Request/Response model which is a subset of a web server.

Comment: @AzamFarooqi - For your goal, look at Google Cloud Run. This is similar to Cloud Functions but allows you to basically host anything that will run in a container. Very inexpensive, powerful and managed for you. Very close to perfection for Flask.